# Not able to check error logs while developing PWA in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, progressive-web-apps

I am working on Flutter PWA, in the console I am not able to check the error logs (similar to android error logs) after executing the command.

I tried working on VS code and Android studio

How should I check the error logs while developing for Flutter PWA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print()` statement will automatically print the output in the VS code debug console.
To open debug console in vs code goto `View->Debug Console` or use a key shortcut `CTRL+SHIFT+Y`

Answer (score 0):

You should Use the print statement and check in run tab not logcat

Example Code :

```
  try{

  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email:_email , password:_password);
        }
    catch(e){
          print(e.message);
        }
```

Comment: Where could I see the the log of `print('message');` while working Flutter PWA in Android Studio or VS Code ?